# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'price' | Issues with *args usage. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, function, class, tuples, args

```
class product():

  def __init__(self, price, product_id, quantity):
     self.price = price
     self.product_id = product_id
     self.quantity = quantity


def calculate_value(*stuff):

   print(sum(stuff.price*stuff.quantity))


a = product(2,"a", 2)
b = product(3, "b", 3)

calculate_value(a,b)


Error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/apple/Desktop/Python/product_inventory_project.py", 
line 17, in <module>
calculate_value(a,b)
File "/Users/apple/Desktop/Python/product_inventory_project.py", 
line 11, in calculate_value
print(sum(stuff.price*stuff.quantity))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'price'
```

What am I doing wrong here? I feel the *args in calculate_value is causing  issues, but I am unable to see the fault. Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You would need to loop over `stuff` to access each `product` that was passed

```
def calculate_value(*stuff):
    return sum(i.price * i.quantity for i in stuff)
```

Output

```
>>> calculate_value(a, b)
13
```

Comment: I see, python sees stuff here as a  tuple automatically?

Comment: Basically, yes. Canonically these are referred to as [`*args` and `**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs) and represent positional and named arguments respectively.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `*args` (or `*stuff`) then it is a tuple of all of the arguments that are passed in (or technically all of the remaining arguments).  So when you call `calculate_value(...)` with two arguments, `stuff` is now a tuple of two items.  If you called `calculate_value(...) with one argument,` stuff`would be a tuple of one item.  Regardless, you need to iterate (or something) over the tuple to get to the`product`items you pass in. You are treating`stuff`like an instance of`product`, but it's not.  It's a tuple.  Hence the error saying` tuple`object has no`price` attribute.